# I have set useSSL=false but I am still getting the warning

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm setting up a Hibernate project without hibernate.xml.

So I configured Hibernate like this:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
            try {
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Configuration cnf = new Configuration();

                // Properties
                cnf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                cnf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db?useSSL=false‌​");
                cnf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");     
                cnf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "root");
                cnf.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
                cnf.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
                cnf.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
                cnf.setProperty(" hibernate.connection.pool_size", "1");

                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cnf.getProperties());
                sessionFactory = cnf.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        // Class mappings
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

When I execute the Hibernate logs this line:
    `INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db?useSSL=false‌​]`

After executing I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at core.Tester.main(Tester.java:10)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
at database.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:34)
... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:123)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:20)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:161)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:109)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The connection property 'useSSL' only accepts values of the form: 'true', 'false', 'yes' or 'no'. The value 'false‌​' is not in this set.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.validateStringValues(ConnectionPropertiesImpl.java:314)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$BooleanConnectionProperty.initializeFrom(ConnectionPropertiesImpl.java:91)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.initializeFrom(ConnectionPropertiesImpl.java:216)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl.initializeProperties(ConnectionPropertiesImpl.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializeDriverProperties(ConnectionImpl.java:3153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:774)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
... 29 more
```

I don't see what I could be doing wrong since it logs out the connection URL as expected. And I don't see how it could be an encoding error.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Hibernate, its the MySQL driver that's throwing a fit. Which version is it? This smells buggy

Comment: @Gimby I'm using this version [MySQL Connector/J » 6.0.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.6)

Comment: What if you change it to `no`?

Comment: @Kayaman Yes I have and I still an a similar warning.

Comment: Maybe there's some 0 length character that's gotten in there. Try removing the line and rewriting it by hand. It's hard to imagine this being a driver error.

Comment: @Kayaman You are right, I wrote it by hand and it worked. Thanks

Comment: No problemo, which IDE/OS are you using?

Comment: @Kayaman I'm using Eclipse, does that make a difference?

Comment: I've had an issue with Eclipse (Neon.1, on Ubuntu) inserting a "non-standard space" (maybe nbsp) to places like `if(foo) {` when I'm coding fast, and Eclipse shows the red squiggly line under it, while the code would otherwise seem syntactically correct (and if it were inside a String, I would have no idea there's not a normal space in there). That was what I based my mystery character suggestion on.